# Ubuntu software updating never finishes (Ubutntu 16.04)

Tags: updates, software-center, update-manager, software-sources

I tried to update my Ubuntu 16.04 using the Ubuntu Software but it stays updating indefinitely and block any other installation from the console or in the same APP. It happened at least 3 times and the only solution is a restart.

Is there any way to stop it safely? (no kill command, I'm afraid of corrupting my OS).

Is there any way to find out why it's jammed?

Answer (score 0):

Run the update in a terminal.

Open terminaL:

`ctrl-alt-t`

Update software repository:

`sudo apt update`

Upgrade software:

`sudo apt upgrade`

Then you can see in the output where the problems are.

Comment: I had tried this before, but it doesnt show the same updates, when I run  `sudo apt upgrade` I got:
_0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded._

Comment: Then run ubuntu-software from a terminal. Maybe it has some interesting output.

Comment: I tried, but it is detached from the console. I run it and the console behaves as the task was finished. Also, there is not any output of the app.